# How to reproduce executive summary using Power BI which was created in Excel

Tags: excel, postgresql, powerbi, data-migration

I aplogize beforehand if this questions turns out to be not specific enough. The issue is as following:

I have an excel file in which there are several sheets with lots of calculations (mostly financials). I have access to the same database from where raw excel file was downloaded. Now I want to repreduce the calculations and executive summary using Power BI getting the data from database directly (most likely using Direct Query mode). But I am not sure how should go about it? Should/can I use the existing Excel file to somehow copy the work that has been already done and just change the source to database? Or will I have to do it all over again? One main point when considering the above questions is whether Power BI will be able to do all the complex calculations done in Excel previously?

Via search I came accross to a few videos where they say we can upload Excel file into Power BI and then apply the same tables from database and finally using Advanced Editor change Excel tables sources to database. But thing is that database doesn't have the kind of tables I have in Excel (lots of changes and calculations are applied to the raw data that was downloaded from database). So I am not sure how this method can work.

Comment: Copy what excel does sounds like something you'd do with DAX rather than with PowerQuery. PowerQuery is quite a bit different, DAX is likely to have very similar functions for your use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Monofuse, for the answer. Using DAX will certainly be one of the things I will have try. Though I don't want to make any comments before actually using it for this case, one thing I always encounter is that DirectQuery does very poor job when it comes to using DAX queries (it handles only very simple DAX, giving errors with the rest).

Comment: You can create columns using lambda statements in powerquery by typing out a step by hand, but they aren't clean or simple to make to a person who hasn't used them before. There is no way of converting from an excel formula.